# Html.ActionLink passes null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a View that displays a list of objects. There I have this action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", new {str = Model.First().directory})
```

And this is the method in the controller.

```
public ActionResult Add(string parentDirectory)
{
    UserService.Node file = new UserService.Node()
    {
        parent_directory = parentDirectory,
    };
    return View(file);
}
```

For some reason unknown to me `parentDirectory` is always null, even when I tried this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", new {str = "Hello"})
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parameter name of `Add` controller action method is `parentDirectory`, you need to change this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", new { str = Model.First().directory })
```

to this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add", "Add", new { parentDirectory = Model.First().directory })
```

Comment: So the name of the parameter should always be the same as the one in the method ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes exactly. If you change the parameter name in the controller, then you also need to change the parameter name in the third parameter of `@Html.ActionLink` method.